# Recovering grub with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have dual booted Ubuntu (and Red Hat before that) with Windows (notably 7) successfully. I had to get a new machine because of hardware failures and the new one came with Windows 10 pre-installed. I blithely ran the Ubuntu 18.04 install, just as I have done in the past, and this time GRUB did not appear. My machine is a Dell Inspiron. Since Grub doesn't show, I cannot access Ubuntu.

Most discussions of this kind of problem on the web are with Linux installed first and then Windows. I am reluctant to charge ahead without a little more information. My Windows 10 is UEFI enabled.

- Can I run `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}"` path `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` to recover the Grub?
- If this fails, how do I undo the command?

TIA

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? Need details: Just run the summary report and post link it gives, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Use second option or install into Ubuntu live installer using ppa.

Comment: Is this an Acer machine? (as they have an issue with putting grub in the NVRAM so it's there, but Windows Boot Manager still gets executed as priority 0.)